# Converting from Windows MBCS to UTF-8

Tags: unicode, visual-studio-2015, utf-8, mbcs

I have a very large (millions of lines) application which was developed using MBCS (codepage 1252) and assumes all strings are char* and each character is only one byte. We are now expanding our language set and need to move to Unicode. Since UTF-8 works in 1-byte increments, it seems that this would be a good fit. Per the usual, we would like to make this change with the minimal amount of code change. We would not like to change everything to wchar or _TCHAR and have to modify the way every source file is encoded if we can help it.

The only way these foreign characters would be used is if the user entered them in a field, such as name. Strings containing these characters are then saved to files as needed and are not manipulated. The files are read later and the contents displayed. Assuming that no characters outside of cp1252 (ie chinese characters, etc) are used in the source code, do we need to make any changes to the majority of the source code, or can we leave it as char* and just let the possibly multi-byte characters pass through the system until they reach the UI where they are displayed?

The application is developed on Visual Studio 2015 using MFC.

Comment: The Win32 API (mostly) does not support UTF-8. So, even if you decide to use UTF-8 in your in-memory strings, you will have to convert them between UTF-16 at runtime when passing them to/from Win32 API functions. And you will have to use a Unicode-based UI. That is going to be a much larger code change than just using Unicode strings everywhere in the first place.  The *minimum* amount of code change would have been accomplished if you were using `TCHAR` and `TCHAR`-based APIs, but that is not the case if you were using `char` directly.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a good choice to use to encode your data going forward.  Support for it on Windows is getting better, but you still would want to convert your UTF-8 strings to and from strings of `wchar_t` (that is, UTF-16 on Windows) in order to use them with the Windows API.  (There’s limited support in Windows for reading and writing UTF-8 with the console using CP 65001, but your app is probably not console-mode.) You can do this with `<codecvt>` (`std::codecvt_utf8` or `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`), `widen()` and `narrow()` in Boost, `mbstowcs()` in C, or various other libraries such as ICU or QT.

UTF-8 support on Windows seems to be improving.  There is even a `".utf8"` or `".utf-8"` locale in the latest Windows 10SR4. You still probably won’t be able to use a UTF-8 locale in your apps for a long time, if they have to run on older versions.

You’ll also need to be able to convert your legacy data to UTF-8, but the same libraries can handle that as well.  For example, you can get a `codecvt` facet from a `std::locale` object initialized to the code page the data was saved in.  Or just use a lookup table.

There’s not much reason to save your data in anything but UTF-8.  UTF-16 takes up more space, it isn’t even a fixed-width encoding, has trouble with endianness, and isn’t as widely-used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a [very detailed page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tgbl/concept_UnderstandingCharacterSets-0769d6.html) talking about the topic. (search: `CP1252` on the page, all 'Character Sets' are listed at the bottom.)

`MBCS` stands for : Multi Byte Character Sets.

`cp-1252` **is not** `MBCS` :
`cp-1252` encompasses the `ASCII char-set` (128 symbols), extended with 128 more symbols : 256 symbols, encoded on 1 byte per symbol.

As `MBCS` can hold 1 or 2 bytes per symbol, it includes `cp-1252` (256 1-byte symbols), but it holds many more symbols than `cp-1252`.
See Microsoft, about [Unicode and MBCS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0.aspx).

If you have python installed, inside the file `your_path_to\Python27\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py` you can see it clearly : from `0x00` to  `0xFF` : one single byte per symbol (2 * 4 bits), 256 symbols.

About internationalization, Microsoft helps ?